# Notepad++: disable automatic list numbering

Tags: notepad++

I'm outlining a book and storing the information in a text file in Notepad++.  The book is divided into sections, which I am numbering, but every time I press enter, Notepad++ automatically inserts the next number in the sequence.  For instance, if I type "1.2 The World Wide Web" + enter, the next line begins with "2.".  I don't want this.  How do I disable the automatic numbering?

Comment: What plugins do you have installed? As far as I'm aware, this isn't something that is even possible with vanilla Notepad++.

Comment: I have installed quite a few: Compare, DSpellCheck, Emmet, HTML Tag, Notepad#, CCompletion, Converter, NppExport, NppFTP, NppPlates, Quick Color Picker +, NppSync, Preview HTML, Python Script, Spell-Checker, Tidy2, XML Tools.  I'll check each one to see if the answer lies in there.  I may habe missed something.

Comment: There is an auto-numbering feature in Notepad# -- "Automatic numbering inside CommentDoc/DocBlock and # comment", but I'm not sure if this pertains to my problem.  CCompletion could also be problematic.  I'll try uninstalling them to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I uninstalled Notepad# and the autonumbering is no more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with vanilla Notepad++.  It is a problem with a plugin, namely Notepad#, which has an auto-numbering feature.  I didn't see an option to disable the feature within the plugin, but after uninstalling it the auto-numbering went away.  Thanks to senshin for pointing out that it was a plugin issue.

Comment: thanks for Notepad#, i did try alot to find a plugin for auto-numbered-list in NPP :)